# Python Email, how to delete/refresh 'To' field in a message

Tags: python, email, msg

I'm trying to write a python rogram to send email to multiple addresses.

Each time the message is the same except for the recipient's address.
I thought i could just change the msg['To'] in the loop,

```
for email in emaillist
   ...
   msg['To'] = email
   ...
   ...
```

but actually each time 'email' is appended to the msg['To'].

msg.as_string() is like 'To: abc@gmail.com\nTo:xyz@gmail.com'

How can I replace the msg['To'] field rather than appending?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `del msg['To']` to clear. The = operator adds rather than replaces. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html) for `__setitem__` for details.